# Push can not get UI instance using Spring

Tags: spring, vaadin7

I am trying to send a message from a Spring Service to a Vaadin View using "ru.xpoft.vaadin" plugin.

All my views and UI are working using prototype scope, but when I try to send a message from a service "singleton scope" to my view it gets null for the  current UI.

Is there any reason for it? UI.getCurrent() returns null.

I'd appreciate any help.

For example:

```
@Service
class service{
  public void send(){
    Broadcaster.broadcast("miau");
  }
}

@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@VaadinView(value = "myView")
class MyView implements BroadcastListener{

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  Broadcaster.register(this);
}

@Override
public void receiveBroadcast(final String message) {
  UI.getCurrent().access(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     LOGGER.info(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + message);
    }
  });
}

  @Override
  public void detach() {
    Broadcaster.unregister(this);
  }
}
```